# Is StringBuilder threadsafe (using it with parallelStream)?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java-8, stringbuilder

My code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

events.parallelStream().forEach(event -> {
    sb.append(event.toString());
    sb.append("\n");
});
```

I don't care about the order of the `events.toString()` in the final result. But I care that the `events.toString()` will correctly appear one line after another, without mixing / messing up of course.

Is `parallelStream` (instead of `stream`) safe in this regard?

Comment: Even if you did use a StringBuffer, you might get two events in a row and then two newlines in a row.

Comment: The answer is no. (might be useful: [How do I prove programmatically that StringBuilder is not threadsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558432))

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The better solution is to use

```
events.parallelStream().map(event -> event+"\n").collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Or alternatively (thanks to @Holger):

```
events.parallelStream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n", "", "\n"));
```

In general avoid using `forEach` as terminal operation for streams. Usually reduction operations like `collect` or `reduce` are better alternatives.

Comment: Will the collection of the strings happen after all the work of the parallel streams or in the middle of it? Because I think `parallelStream` uses fork join framework behind the scenes.

Comment: The task will be split to parts and they will be independently joined in parallel. Finally the parts will be merged together into the resulting string. It uses `StringBuilder` internally, but different parts use different instances, so no problems with synchronization here.

Comment: Still better: `events.parallelStream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n", "", "\n"));`

Comment: Thanks, added your version to the answer.

Comment: Regarding `forEach` it should be noted that it is *not ordered*, so even with an appropriate synchronization within the lambda expression it wouldn’t produce the desired result. `forEachOrdered` would solve this, together with the threading issue, but be way slower than `collect` in most cases.

Comment: My toString() method for the Event class is overloaded, is it then an issue with Object::toString?

Comment: @seinecle, nope, not a problem. Using `Event::toString` or `event -> event.toString()` is fine as well.

Comment: @seinecle: the correct term is *overridden* and, you know, with overridden methods, if you call `((Object)event).toString()` you still end up in `Event`’s `toString()` method. The same applies to `Object::toString` or method references in general; for instance methods, they will invoke the overriding method, if there is one.

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not thread-safe.

This is the main difference between the old `StringBuffer` and the new `StringBuilder` - the former's methods are synchronized, while the latter's are not.

It's not very useful to do it this way, even if you'd use `StringBuffer` instead - the threads would have to wait on each other to write to the `StringBuffer`.

Comment: And not to forget, even when using `StringBuffer`, the two `append` calls made within the lambda expression could be arbitrary interleaved when the lambda expression is executed concurrently without additional synchronization.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not. As noted in [its javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

> A mutable sequence of characters. This class provides an API compatible with StringBuffer, but **with no guarantee of synchronization**.

Use `StringBuffer` instead.

Comment: Note that you will unlikely to benefit from parallelization if you use `StringBuffer` in this case. I'm pretty sure it will be even slower than sequential stream as actually nothing will be performed in parallel; all the threads except one will just wait on monitors.

Comment: @TagirValeev That's not true. The events' toString methods will be executed in parallel.